# how to load user data into an input?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the data of the logged in user to be loaded into the entries, but I don't know how to do that. Do I have to use something similar like innerText?

code HTML:

```
<form>
        <h2 align="center">Setting</h2>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="uidInput" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Uid</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control teste" id="uidInput" placeholder="uidInput">
            </div>
            <label for="emailInput" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailInput">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="nameInput" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameInput">
            </div>
            <label for="passwordInput" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordInput">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="surnameInput" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Surname</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surnameInput">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="numberInput" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">document number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numberInput">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

code js:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var name = snapshot.val().name;
    var surname = snapshot.val().surname;
    var documentNumber = snapshot.val().documentNumber;
    var email = snapshot.val().email;
    var password = snapshot.val().password;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the values you read from the database into the HTML, you can indeed set the inner text of the elements with something like:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var name = snapshot.val().name;
    var surname = snapshot.val().surname;
    var documentNumber = snapshot.val().documentNumber;
    var email = snapshot.val().email;
    var password = snapshot.val().password;

    document.querySelection('#emailInput').textContent = email;
    document.querySelection('#nameInput').textContent = name;
    document.querySelection('#passwordInput').textContent = password;
    document.querySelection('#surnameInput').textContent = surname;
    document.querySelection('#numberInput').textContent = documentNumber;
})
```